# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fbind' error using kivy in Python

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7, attributeerror

Been programming a Kivy interface for a Caesar cypher I've done a few days ago and I'm running into an error (see title) I can't seem to get through. I'll put my code underneath, as well as the full traceback which can probably help.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Cypher:

    def __init__(self):

        MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26


    '''def getMode(self)        

        while True:



            print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
            mode = input().lower()
            if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
                return mode
            else:
                print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')'''

    def getMessage(self):

            print('Enter your message:')
            return input()

    def getKey(self):

            key = 0
            while True:
                print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
                key = int(input())
                if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
                    return key

    def getTranslatedMessage(self, mode, message, key):

        '''if mode[0] == 'd':
            key = -key'''

        self.msg = ''

        self.msg += message

        translated = ''

        for char in self.msg:
            if char.isalpha():
                num = ord(char)
                num += key
                if char.isupper():
                    if num > ord('Z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('A'):
                        num += 26
                elif char.islower():
                    if num > ord('z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('a'):
                        num += 26
                translated += chr(num)
            else:
                translated += char

        return translated

    def func(self):

        mode = self.getMode()
        message = self.getMessage()

        key = self.getKey()


#    print('Your translated text is:')

        return self.getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key)


class StartPageKivy(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        c = Cypher()

        self.cols = 2

        self.encButton = Button(text='Encrypt')
        self.encButton.bind(on_press = self.encryptionMode)
        self.add_widget(self.encButton)
        self.decButton = Button(text='Decrypt')
        self.decButton.bind(on_press = self.decryptionMode)
        self.add_widget(self.decButton)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Insert the key'))
        self.key = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.key)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Insert the message'))
        self.message =  TextInput(multiline=False).text
        self.add_widget(self.message)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='The result is :'))

        self.mode = ''

        while self.mode not in 'e d':

            if self.encryptionMode() == True:
                self.mode = 'e'
            elif self.decryptionMode() == True:
                self.mode = 'd'

        self.result = c.getTranslatedMessage(self.mode, self.message, self.key)

        self.add_widget(Label(text=self.result))

    def encryptionMode(self, instance):

        return True

    def decryptionMode(self, instance):

        return True

class EpicApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return StartPageKivy()

class StartPageTkinter():

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    EpicApp().run()
```

> runfile('C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms/AveCypher.py', >wdir='C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>      runfile('C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms/AveCypher.py', >wdir='C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms')
>
> File "C:\Users\danburnier\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
>      execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\danburnier\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
>      exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms/AveCypher.py", line 152, in 
>      EpicApp().run()
>
> File "C:\Users\danburnier\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, >in run
>      root = self.build()
>
> File "C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms/AveCypher.py", line 145, in build
>      return StartPageKivy()
>
> File "C:/Users/danburnier/Desktop/PythonPrograms/AveCypher.py", line 117, in **init**
>      self.add_widget(self.message)
>
> File "C:\Users\danburnier\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", >line 92, in add_widget
>      fbind = widget.fbind
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fbind'

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an environment to run your code, but looking at the traceback my guess is the problem is here:

```
    self.message =  TextInput(multiline=False).text
    self.add_widget(self.message)
```

The problem is probably the '.text' at the end of the first line. My guess is text (stored in self.message here) is not a valid widget. Try removing '.text' or changing the second line to:

```
    self.add_widget(Label(text=self.message))
```